# How do I return a FileStreamResult from a View in MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

In my Controller I have a GenerateDocument method that returns a FileStreamResult.

In my view I have javascript that simply opens a new like so; window.open('/controller/GenerateDocument/?id=blah');

I need my GenerateDocument method to:
1. return a pdf when the document can be created/fetched without errors,
2. return a new page/view when there are errors.

Here's the Controller code:

```
    public FileStreamResult GenerateDocument(int id)
    {
        string errorResult = string.Empty;

        try
        {
            DocumentDetail documentDetail =
                 DocumentGenerator.GenerateAgreements(id, DcmDocumentEntityType.Sponsor, GetAuthUser());

            if (documentDetail == null) return null;

            Stream stream = DocumentGenerator.RetrieveFile(documentDetail);

            return new FileStreamResult(stream, "application/pdf");
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            errorResult = FormatException(ex);
            Trace.TraceError(errorResult);
        }

        //ViewBag.Error = HttpUtility.HtmlEncode(errorResult).Replace("\n", "<br />");

        //return View("DocGenerationError");
        return null;
    }
```

I tried using using ActionResult and returning the view in case of an error, but as I noted in a comment on this thread, in the page javascript, window.open(url) would not work right.

Here's the view code:

```
  $('#ActionMenu').change(function() {
      var action = $(this).val();

      switch (action) {            
      case 'Generate Sponsor Agreement':
          window.open('/Sponsor/GenerateDocument/?id=@(Model.SponsorID)');
          break;

      other cases

      default:
      }
  });
```

Note: the Controller code above WORKS. It's when I switch to returning an ActionResult and uncomment out the exception handling stuff that it stops working.

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure I understand your problem.  What's wrong with doing this?

```
public ActionResult GenerateDocument() {
     ..... // Do code
     if (errors)
         return View(errorModel);
     return new FileStreamResult(...); // your pdf file
}
```

Comment: I had tried it that way first and couldn't get it to work. I have no idea why it wouldn't work, I just know that window.open would not pop up a new window.

Comment: @PaulRivera - Then this has nothing to do with the server-side code.  Your problem is client-side javascript related.  If it were a problem on the server, the window would pop up and you would see an error in the window.  Show your view code.

Answer (score 2):

You can do this simply using the Controller.File method which returns a FilePathResult. There are a number of overloads, but here is an example:

```
return File(streamreader.ReadToEnd(), "text/plain", "Result.PDF");
```

You do not need to change the return type of the action as FilePathResult inherits from ActionResult, so in the case of an error you can return the view to handle this.